# How to detect and correct swap errors in a quantum circuit?

Tags: error-correction, quantum-operation, quantum-circuit

Let's assume that I have a density matrix $\rho$ that consists of $N$ qubits.

If this density matrix undergoes an error-channel that swaps any two qubits with an equal probability, i.e.

$$
\mathcal{E}(\rho)=(1-p)\rho + \frac{2p}{N(N-1)}\sum_{i=1}^{N-1}\sum_{j>i}^N \mathrm{SWAP}_{ij}\rho \mathrm{SWAP}_{ij}
$$
where $p$ is the probability of an error.

Does there exist a quantum circuit/protocol that can detect and correct if a swap error has occurred?

Comment: Could you not just use a distance 5 error correcting code, since this can correct for any error on 2 or fewer sites? That presumably includes your swap case. Or are you hoping for something more specialised?

Comment: Alternatively, perhaps you could encode in the fully symmetric subspace. That's a decoherence-free subspace for that noise, so you don't even have to apply any error correction.